# Comment choisir entre une traduction en français et une traduction en Anglais d’une œuvre écrite dans une langue que je ne lis pas?

Tags: traduction, anglais, littérature

Je lis l’Anglais et le Français, prends plaisir à lire de la littérature dans les deux langues, et me réjouis de pouvoir lire à la fois [*Le Réel et son double*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_R%C3%A9el_et_son_double) et [*A History of Violence*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_History_of_Violence_(comics)) dans leurs langues respectives.

Cependant, si je veux lire [*Der Zauberberg*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Montagne_magique), [*Идиот*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Idiot) ou [*Il Barone rampante*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Baron_perch%C3%A9), et bien je dois recourir à une traduction, ne lisant ni l’Allemand, ni le Russe, ni l’Italien (entre autres).

**Comment évaluer la valeur des traductions en Anglais et en Français** lorsque j’ai accès aux deux traductions?

En sachant que je n’ai pas le bagage ni le temps pour lire les deux éditions et les comparer, consulter des thèses d’experts sur ces auteurs, ou autres. Quel critères peuvent m’aider à prendre rapidement une décision quand à quelle édition rechercher?

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language. Cette question n'est pas directement une question qui porte directement sur la langue et de plus aucune réponse ne peut être objective. Consulte [cette page](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) pour voir le genre de question à éviter. Je ne sais pas si sur [literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) ils répondent à ce genre de question. Quand je cherche une traduction je lis les critiques des spécialistes. Quand la traduction de la dernière traduction de *La Montagne Magique* est parue (2016, chez Fayard) les critiques étaient dithyrambiques.

Comment: Mais pas toutes. Cherche un peu. https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/discussion/66699/quelle-traduction-de-thomas-mann. https://www.critiqueslibres.com/i.php/forum/sujet/13023 https://www.lemonde.fr/livres/article/2016/11/02/la-montagne-magique-reenchantee_5024280_3260.html  https://www.lexpress.fr/culture/livre/ces-classiques-de-la-litterature-en-quete-d-une-seconde-jeunesse_1820824.html

Comment: Quand la dernière traduction de ...

Comment: Si vous n'avez pas trouvé de solution avec @None, le plus simple est de sélectionner les traductions françaises de langue latine (et russe, car on a parlé français dans la haute société russe du temps du tsar) et anglaises pour les langues nordiques.

Comment: Merci pour vos commentaires. Je pense que la combinaison des trois « règles » que @Personne et None suggèrent font une base … assez objective, justement. a) latine => Français, nordique => Anglais b) Récent >>> Vieux c) Lire les critiques (si on a le temps). J’essayerai peut-être sur literature si la question ne génère pas d’interêt ici, merci pour la suggestion.

Comment: Question posée sur https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/20325/4296 N’hésitez pas à y poster vos réponses si vous en avez :-)